# How to do "R CMD SHLIB" multiple .c and .f files

Tags: c, r, fortran

I have .c files and .f files which are interdependent.
That means, the function used in .c files are defined in .f files.

Now, I want to call for some functions in .c file from my R. How can I do this using R CMD SHLIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I figured out this can be easily done by

```
  R CMD SHLIB code1.f  code2.c -o myLib
```

Then in R, I can call the myLib via

```
  dyn.load("myLib")
```

Comment: Also, perhaps, see `?SHLIB` for more info